# update seaborn from inside jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Here my problem:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=[x,x,x], y=[x,x,x])
```

> > > AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'scatterplot'

I read that seaborn needs to be updated, to solve this. So I did:

```
!pip install seaborn --upgrade #or also !pip install seaborn==0.9.0
import seaborn as sns
sns.__version__
```

> > > 0.8.1

It's not updating, and I keep getting the same AttributeError. What am I missing?

Comment: It might help to read this: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling seaborn.

Comment: try reinstalling seaborn and then restarting your notebook. Some cloud environments like google colab need to be restarted to get the right version after upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I just used Anaconda Prompt to update seaborn.

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

and then I restarted Anaconda and it works now.

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

Update jupyter notebook in the Anaconda navigator. All modules will get updated. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issues after upgrading seaborn but it worked just fine once I restarted my kernel.